# Navigation button based on a PowerApps dropdown value

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have been trying to set mandatory dropdowns to be selected in order to go to the next screen.

- Next screen is called ***End***
- Dropdown is called ***type_4***

This is the code that I used but it doesn't seem to go through:

```
If(
    IsBlank(type_4.Selected.Value),
    Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error),
    Navigate(End,ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

This issue is specific to dropdown inputs. If it was a text field all I do is replacing ***Selected.Value*** by ***Text*** and it works fine.
Dropdowns are my only problem so far.

**EDIT**: The default value of the dropdowns is ***Select your answer*** (first choice of the dropdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default option for your dropdown is 'Select your answer', then you can use an expression similar to the one below:

```
If(
    type_4.Selected.Value = "Select your answer",
    Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error),
    Navigate(End,ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Carlos, what would you write if there were two dropdowns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876955/navigation-button-based-on-several-powerapps-dropdown-values

Comment: You can use the [Or operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals) or the [Or function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals) to combine multiple conditions: `If(type_4.Selected.Value = "Select your answer" Or type_3.Selected.Value = "Select your answer", Notify("Fill all fields to continue", NotificationType.Error), Navigate(End, ScreenTransition.Cover))`