# Navigation button based on several PowerApps dropdown values

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am trying to set mandatory dropdowns to be selected in order to go to the next screen.

- Next screen is called ***End***
- First dropdown is called ***type_4***
- Second dropdown is called ***type_3***
- Third dropdown is called ***type_2***

Please note that the default value of the dropdowns is ***Select your answer*** (first choice of the dropdown).

This is the code that I used but it doesn't seem to go through:

```
If(
    IsBlank(type_4.Selected.Value), 
    IsBlank(type_3.Selected.Value), 
    IsBlank(type_2.Selected.Value),
    Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error),
    Navigate(End,ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default option for your dropdowns is 'Select your answer', then you can use the [Or function (or the Or operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals) to combine the conditions, in an expression similar to the one below:

```
If(
    Or(
        type_4.Selected.Value = "Select your answer",
        type_3.Selected.Value = "Select your answer",
        type_2.Selected.Value = "Select your answer"),
    Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error),
    Navigate(End,ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos!